# public key cryptography and authentication for cross-platform network application

Tags: security, authentication, encryption, cryptography, zeromq

I'm developing network based application for control and telemetry on Linux based embedded system. I'm using **ZMQ** network library and Google **Protocol Buffers** serialization library for communication purposes.

I took a look at [CurveZMQ](http://curvezmq.org/page:read-the-docs) however there is no official binding for C++ and I do not want to mess up my implementation with CZMQ binding. Therefore I decided that I do not want to use CurveZMQ extension and **I want to use some external library for authentication and encryption.**

**I want to apply following security measurements to my application/system:**

1. "CURVE" security mechanism, to give me strong encryption on data, and (as far as we know) unbreakable authentication.
2. Client public key authentication.
3. I would appriciate library with binding to many programming languages because my client application is going to run on many different platforms.

**Nice to have:**

1. Curve25519 elliptic curve cryptography (ECC) algorithm.

I believe I can encapsulate handshake messages in my Protocol Buffers messages.. **So basically the idea is to establish secure tunnel between server and client and somehow enforce client and server authentication.** Below you can find how my unsecure system is working and where I imagine to put encryption layer. I do not have any idea how to solve authentication issue at the moment.

Here is the big picture of my not secure system.

```
 ______________________                       ______________________
|                      |                     |                      |  APPLICATION
|        client        |                     |        server        |  LAYER
|      application     |                     |      application     |
|______________________|                     |______________________|
       /\      ||                                   /\      ||
       ||      ||                                   ||      ||
 ______||______\/______                       ______||______\/______
|                      |                     |                      |  SERIALIZATION
|       protobuf       |                     |       protobuf       |  DESERIALIZATION
|______________________|                     |______________________|  LAYER
       /\      ||                                   /\      ||
       ||      ||                                   ||      ||
 ______||______\/______                       ______||______\/______
|                      |                     |                      |  TRANSPORT
| zmq_socket.send(...) |-------------------->| zmq_socket.recv(...) |  LAYER
|                      |      (TCP/IP)       |                      |
| zmq_socket.recv(...) |<--------------------| zmq_socket.send(...) |
|______________________|                     |______________________|
     python client                                  C++ server
```

Here is how I imagine my secure system.

```
 ______________________                       ______________________
|                      |                     |                      |  APPLICATION
|        client        |                     |        server        |  LAYER
|      application     |                     |      application     |
|______________________|                     |______________________|
       /\      ||                                   /\      ||
       ||      ||                                   ||      ||
 ______||______\/______                       ______||______\/______
|                      |                     |                      |  SERIALIZATION
|       protobuf       |                     |       protobuf       |  DESERIALIZATION
|______________________|                     |______________________|  LAYER
       /\      ||                                   /\      ||
       ||      ||                                   ||      ||
 ______||______\/______                       ______||______\/______
|                      |                     |                      |  ENCRYPTION
|      encryption      |                     |      encryption      |  LAYER
|______________________|                     |______________________|
       /\      ||                                   /\      ||
       ||      ||                                   ||      ||
 ______||______\/______                       ______||______\/______
|                      |                     |                      |  TRANSPORT
| zmq_socket.send(...) |-------------------->| zmq_socket.recv(...) |  LAYER
|                      |      (TCP/IP)       |                      |
| zmq_socket.recv(...) |<--------------------| zmq_socket.send(...) |
|______________________|                     |______________________|
     python client                                  C++ server
```

***Basically I need help with making my system secure. Could you help me with that?***

Comment: I'm trying to solve this problem by my own. I'm optimistic towards NaCl library which has binding for C++ and python and few other languages which at this point is good enough for me. I've found nice example of public key encryption with the help of this library. It seems quite easy however I still do not know how to put all (authentication + encryption) security measurements together. Here is the link to mentioned example https://pynacl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/public/

Comment: Unfortunately, this question isn't a good fit for StackOverflow as it's asking for a 3rd party library rec. I suggest you go to the [zmq mailing list](http://zeromq.org/docs:mailing-lists) as people there will likely be familiar with the problem and have some good recommendations. Many of us have run into this issue, I, for instance, solved it myself in node.js by writing [onecrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/onecrypt) (which, if you trust it, could provide a template for you), but odds are there are more common encryption packages available in C++ for you that would be a better fit.

Comment: The thing is I need more than just a library I would really appreciate some flowcharts how to establish secure tunnel, how to exchange the keys etc. Because I'm afraid that it is very easy to create security vulnerability during implementation even based on recognized 3rd party library especially when someone never did it before - like me.

Comment: I have to solve problem in my system, here is my current state and I'm searching for advice of people much more experienced than me with expertise in the public key cryptography domain. I really want HOWTO tips in order to make my application a real dill. Unfortunately this domain is a little bit ambiguous for me at the moment,

Comment: There's no good way to give you any information that would be common to any library.  Your best bet is to pick a library, say the NaCl as you mentioned in the first comment, get as far as you can, and write up a new question on where you get stuck.

Comment: Ok. Probably it will be kind of review request post because I expect that I will be able establish secure tunnel without implementation problems however I don't have any idea how to provide authentication for my system.

Comment: I understand the ambiguity, there's a distinct lack of simple, solid advice, just deep info that you have to immerse yourself in for some time before you start to make sense of it.

Comment: You are right. Thank you for the comments for sure I will put an effort every evening to gather information and work on implementation. Therefore I'm leaving this topic open because It is possible to receive some good advises anyways.